# My app getting crashed

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-webview

I have developed an app , I was happy with that when I run on my emulator and on my friends mobile like Mi , coolpad, Moto E2  . The main problem came to me when this app got installed on Moto X play, Samsung Galaxy j7 and infix note 4 my app is getting crashed after displaying splash screen pls help me out here

I am building Apk every time to test on multiple devices but it's runing fine on my emulator and some other devices , there was no error showing in logs , when I installed this app on moto X play runs on custom rom (linage Os ) , one plus X (oxygen os ) , and on infix note 4 its getting crashed after splash screen

Comment: Not everyone here is "bro".

Comment: If your app crashes it crashes for a reason. It's your job to try and narrow down those reasons, to come up with specific evidence of what might be causing the problem, such as *specific errors* or *diagnostic output of any kind*. What you have here is a whole lot of nothing. Can you pop this into a debugger? Can you extract logs from your device? Does it crash in the simulator? There's like ten things you could do here before asking this question.

Comment: @tadman it's not crashing on emulator working fine on some mobiles not working with some other mobiles as I mentioned in above questions

Comment: There's still zero information here. Maybe your phone is broken. Maybe your OS is corrupted. Maybe your app has a gigantic bug in it. In order to narrow this down you need to come up with a probable cause.

Comment: @tadman okay thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use drawable in all screen sizes
and all have your drawables
you need to use layout width & height "match parent , wrap content" or use weight to take size in it

Good luck

Comment: How to transfer data from push notifcatin  to another activity when it is clicked for example ( notification : today's temp is 18 degrees C. So when pressed on it the same data should appear on the activity that opens when we press it how to ?